# Pass a method to another React component (not child)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

I have 2 DIVs: "container-1" and "container-2"
I have 2 components: "Button" and "Board"

Button must be rendered to "container-1"
Board must be rendered to "container-2"

Board has a method - doSomething()

How to call this method from the button which is not child of the Board?
I cant pass doSomething() method to button's props.

Thank you.

```
<div id="container-1">

  <script type="text/babel">

    class Button extends React.Component
    {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
          }

          handleClick() {
            this.props.methodToCall()
          }
          
      render() { 
        return <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={this.handleClick} > Click </button> ; }
    };


    ReactDOM.render(
      <Button key={2}/>,
      document.querySelector("#container-1")
    )

  </script>

</div>




<div id="container-2">
 
  <script type="text/babel">


    class Board extends React.Component
    {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
          }

        doSomething(){
          alert("Method executed")
        }
          

      render() { 
        return <div className="board">
                    
               </div>; }
    };



    ReactDOM.render(
      <Board key={1}/>,
      document.querySelector("#container-2")
    )

  
  </script>

</div>
```

Comment: try to read this https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components 


In react we generally put things which are common like this in a common ancestor, or you can look at  context API or redux for solving your use case